# what is object and attribute in ontology?

Tags: object, ontology, class-hierarchy

I have just created class hierarchy for smartphones ontology using protege.What do i have to do after this?Using that ontology i have to retrieve tweets.So please help me how to develop a simple complete ontology.If possible please mention your mail id for further contacts.I need to develop this ontology for my final year project.

Comment: You'll need to add tweets to the ontology - in this case I imagine they will be individuals. Or is the assignment to retrieve tweets /about/ smartphones?

Comment: Yes.I have to retrieve tweets about smartphone by using the ontology that i am about to create.Is it possible for you to elaborate the whole process.My base paper is " ontology based sentiment analysis of twitter posts " by Efstratios kontopoulos. it will be really helpful.

Comment: The process is far from well defined - there are plenty of alternative approaches, depending on your exact requirements. To start with, outline what you mean by "retrieve using an ontology" - do you plan to take a tweet, classify it according to your ontology, and consider it a result for a query directed at the ontology? That would create three tasks: choose the query language, describe a tweet in terms of your ontology, and actually run a classification, for example with a reasoner.

Comment: Thank you.But how to describe a tweet in terms of my ontology?

Answer (score 0):

That's hard to answer, you might use any of the text analysis frameworks like GATE to find an association between your ontology and the tweet text, or parts of it, like any tags. But that's very open ended - do you have an example of a tweet, and of a query for which you'd expect the tweet to be returned? That would help speculate on a solution.